# How to visualize a single document on a Kibana 8.8 dashboard

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, dashboard, opensearch

I have a seemingly simple problem but have not yet figured out how to do this in a Kibana dashboard.

Lets say I have an index named "companies" with the following document structure:

name: string
size: long
revenue: long

Now all I want to create is a dashboard which shows this information for a single document. Later on I would like to e.g. link from a different dashboard with maybe a list of companies to this single company view dashboard. This would be very similar to how all fields of a document are shown in the Discovery page. But I want to customize which fields are shown and be able to navigate to it from other dashboards.

E.g. the dashboard could look like this (the first element could be a control where the selected company is shown and can be changed):

### | Name: Company A

Size: 300
Revenue: 20.000
...

I managed to get something close to it by using a control to select the company by name and a visualization using a table. Adding the relevant fields as rows with "number of values" set to 1 and a metric of "Last value of". If I now select only a single entry in the control I have the right data. But unfortunately, I can e.g. only have the field names as columns and not as rows and I am very limited in how I can pesent the data...